# Rebind after ajax is complete

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am currently in the process of working on the app which is through modular pattern.

The problem i am currently getting is that once the Ajax is complete, i want to be able to fire a function within the object. The object i can see but when i specify a function, it fails and comes back as **Undefined**.

JS

```
var TestCase = {
  settings: {
    cu: $('.select'),
  },

  init: function() {
    se = this.settings;
  },

  windowsReady: function() {
    TestCase.init();
    if ($.fn.selectBox) {
      TestCase.selectBind();
    }
  },

  ajaxComp: function() {
    TestCase.init();
    TestCase.selectBind();
  },

  selectBind: function(){
    se.cu.selectBox();
  },

};
```

JS Fire - The selectBind works fine when its loaded through the ready call. However as mentioned before, the ajaxcomplete keeps coming back as Undefined for `TestCase.ajaxComp();` or a direct call for `TestCase.selectBind();` Please note that when i `console.log(TestCase)` it lists all the objects.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  TestCase.windowsReady();
});

$(document).ajaxSuccess(function() {
  console.log(TestCase);
  TestCase.ajaxComp();
  console.log('completed');
});
```

Comment: Why not just put lines 6-8 in the $(document).ready() call?

Comment: What do you mean "comes back as undefined"? You might want to include the whole error message you are receiving.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Thats the only error i am getting. As per my description, i am trying to call `TestCase.ajaxComp()` - it comes back with `undefined`. When i call `TestCase`, it lists all the objects stored within the `TestCase`

Comment: So when I ask *What do you mean "comes back as undefined"?* I don't really need you to repeat the same words again :). I need you to rephrase. See, I would actually expect calling `TestCase.ajaxComp()` to **return** `undefined`, since it doesn't have a `return` statement in it. However, if you're getting an error like `Uncaught ReferenceError: TestCase is not defined`, then that's something different.

Comment: No, i am just getting a undefined, not the uncaught error. How would you recommend i convert that function into something that will return the selectbind

Answer (score 0):

This is happenning because of this line:

```
se = this.settings;
```

The `this` in the scope of your `$(document).ajaxSuccess(...)` method will be the jQuery object, not TestCase object.

Try changing it to `se = TestCase.settings;`